# How to use local.xml to insert a block in Magento 1.8?

Tags: xml, magento

How can I use loca.xml to insert a block?

I want to insert the static block (identifier: footer_links) from the cms into this **footer** block `inside` my **page.xml**, but `before` **footer_links**,

```
<block type="core/template" name="bottom.footer" as="bottom.footer" template="page/html/footer-bottom.phtml">
   <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
   <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>
```

this is the config in my **local.xml**,

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
 <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
            -->
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
</block>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

answer,

```
<reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>footer_links</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```